# Question about items left after a home sale

Tags: contract-law, real-estate

So I did a bit of research that anything that is stated in the contract are to be left to the buyer and that fixtures are also left to the buyer regardless of it being in the contract. My question is what happens if items are mentioned in the house description during the home sale (like what you see on sites on Redfin that's inputted from the MLS) but they weren't listed on the contract? An example is a beer tap cooler is in the house description of the sale but it was not in the contract. Also, the beer tap cooler is not a fixture as it has wheels at the bottom that can be moved.

Country:USA

State:CA

Residential home

And a follow-up question regarding this. If a built-in grill was not bolted in and is easily removed by sliding it out, is it a fixture? The space where the grill would be accounts for most 40-inch grills and not specifically made to the one that is currently placed.

Comment: I bought a house in England in 1995. Different jurisdiction, I know. The sellers left an electric cooking stove, a refrigerator, carpets, and curtains (drapes). All were in 'nothing special' used condition. After 2 weeks, they wrote saying they wanted £1,000 for these items. On informal advice from a lawyer friend, I wrote back saying I had not contracted to purchase them, I didn't want them and that they had 30 days to come and remove them, after which I would feel free to do what I liked with all the items. I never heard any more.

Comment: There would be the opposite question if you moved out and left some things behind, what rights you have to pick them up and for how long.